# How do I overcome this static vs. non-static method runaround?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've used this quick-and-dirty `msgbox` (*long live VB*) routine extensively with `Swing`, for both debugging and user info messages:

```
  public static void msgbox(String s){
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
  }
```

I'm just beginning to learn about Android app development. I found `Toast` in my textbook as being a quick-but-awkward way to show info to the user. Here's the book's code:

```
 String selected="...whatever...";
 Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selected,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 toast.show();
```

So I wrote this:

```
public void msgbox(String message)
{
  android.widget.Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                message,
                                android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show();
}
```

It worked the first time I used it when I only had one class, `MainActivity`. Then I tried to use it with a `Fragment` as follows:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment   {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater 
                 inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        MainActivity.msgbox("Fragment A"); // **********************************

        Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //...               
        return v;
    }
}
```

The error on the `msgbox` line is `Non-static method msgbox cannot be referenced from a static context.`

So I added `static` to the declaration for `msgbox`, which seemed like a good idea since that's how my `Swing` version of `msgbox` is declared:

```
public static void msgbox(String message)
{
  android.widget.Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), // ********************
                                message,
                                android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

That makes the original error go away, but it's replaced by `Non-static method getApplicationContext cannot be referenced from a static context`.

To fix *that* error, I changed the declaration for `msgbox` to include a `Context`:

```
public static void msgbox(Context c, String message)
{
  android.widget.Toast.makeText(c, message, android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show();
}
```

That works and makes perfect sense, but my quick-and-dirty string-parameter-only call to `msgbox` has now vanished. I now have to call `msgbox` like this from `main` ...

`msgbox(getApplicationContext(), "onCreate; about to show fragment A");`

... and like this from a separate class: ...

`MainActivity.msgbox(getActivity(), "Fragment A");`

I tried passing `null` to `Context`, which works with `Swing` `JOptionDialog`, but I get `null pointer exception` with `makeText`, whose first parameter (I thus found out) is documented as `@NonNull`.

Is there a method other than `getApplicationContext` and `getActivity` that I could use as the first parameter to `makeText` that would allow me to make `msgbox` `static`?

Or do I just have to suffer through supplying a `Context` parameter?

On the other hand, since it possible to do so with `Swing`, does anybody have a `static` one-String-parameter msgbox-type method to share? It doesn't have to use `makeText`.

(I struggled a long time to get as comfortable as I thought I was with Java. Android is every bit as daunting and is making me question what the heck I know ....)

Comment: *no, you have to stuck with the context parameter*

Comment: instead of `MainActivity.msgbox("Fragment A")` can't you do `((MainActivity) getActivity()).msgbox("Fragment A")` and then make msgbox() non-static?

Comment: @Gak2--Don't I want `msgbox` to be `static`? It shouldn't be associated with any particular object to be most versatile--am I right about this? Anyway, I want something easily called from any class in a project: `msgbox("blah");`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but consider subclassing Application, and have it construct a static 'singleton object', giving it the application context. Then put your 'msgbox' method in the singleton.

Comment: This is a great way to get context through a static application object.  I am doing this currently, works great!

Answer (score 0):

Context is an extremely important concept in Android.  I suggest you read up on it.

To answer the question, I would highly recommend you put that method to make the Toast in your Fragment.  Use getActivity() for your context.  If you want, you could make a static method in a Utils class that takes Context as a parameter.  Then, access it from your Activity or your Fragment and just pass in this or getActivity(), respectively.

Comment: @night--I'd like to make `msgbox` callable from any class in the app but without specifying a `Context` as a parameter. I guess you're implying that can't be done. Since I obviously know little about `Context` specifically or Android in general, I guess I just can't understand why something like `JOptionPane`--that can be called with a null parent component as first argument--doesn't exist in the Android world.

Comment: @DSlomer64 http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/widget/Toast.java#Toast.makeText%28android.content.Context%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%2Cint%29

might be helpful to understand why you need Context.